# How do I make a website snap to the next anchor point when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am looking at the scroll effect on this site: http://www.monokroom.com
Basically there are anchor points on the page and when you scroll with the mousewheel (no matter how much or how little) is has a rubberband snap effect that streches and jumps to the next section automatically. I don't even know what this is called.

I tried scroll snap but everything with that is horizontal and not vertical.

I would like to be able to include this in a site I am developing and just want a tip on where to look for code that I can use.

Comment: You can add a scroll listener and when it is called, check the scroll direction, see what anchor node is the closest and use [`element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to automatically scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

That site uses an extention (for purchase):

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

---

However you can do something similar with:

```
         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop': $('#YourAnchorIDhere').offset().top
         }, 2000);
```

Here is a code snippet to run for an example.

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop':   $('#anchor123').offset().top
         }, 2000);

         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop':   $('#anchor456').offset().top
         }, 2000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div id="anchor123">Anchor1!</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div id="anchor456">Anchor2</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

We are attaching a jquery animation to scrollTop using offset();

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ -
**Description**: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/ -
**Description**: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

Change the "2000" number in the code to specify the length of time you want .animate({}) to run

Answer (score 0):

Found this on CSS TRICKS. Modified it a little bit and added comments to understand it better.

Here is the article: https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/

```css
/* The general styles for the slides ( \make it take up the whole page) */
.page {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.docScroller {
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%); /* Make the scroll lock every 100% of the screen */
      scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
  -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  -ms-scroll-snap-destination: 100% 0%; /* Snap the divs to the top of the screen*/
      scroll-snap-destination: 100% 0%;
}

.inside { /* style the content of the slide */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding:50px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:50px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  left:-50px;
  width: 100%;
  height:20%;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}


/* Syle the backgrounds of the slides */
.one {
  background: blue;
}

.two {
  background: purple;
}

.three {
  background: red;
}

.four {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS Scroll snapping - TESTING</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/csssnapscrolling.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="docScroller">
   <div class="page one">
     <div class="inside">
     Slide 1
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="page two">
     <div class="inside">
     Slide two
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="page three">
     <div class="inside">
     Slide three
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="page four">
     <div class="inside">
     Slide four
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```